# how to find attendance by date range in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

`manpower` has one_to_many association with `attendance`

`invoice` table has attribute `from_date`, `to_date`

`attendance_table` has attribute `status`,`manpower_id`,and attendance_date.

i am able to render all manpower on invoice#index.
but i dont't know how can i calculate attendance of each manpower and show them in column also considering time duration from invoice table. 
in attendance table 1 is present. and 0 is absent.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>total present</th>
      <th>Total Abesent</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @manpowers.each do |manpower| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= manpower.name %></td>
      <td><%= "" %></td>
      <td><%= "" %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Present - `manpower.attendance.where(attendance_date: from_date..to_date, status: 1).count`

For Absent - `manpower.attendance.where(attendance_date: from_date..to_date, status: 0).count`

You can create scopes in Attendance model and use those in views.

```
class Attendance < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :absent, where(status: 0)
  scope :present, where(status: 1)
  scope :date_between, -> (from_date, to_date) { where(attendance_date: from_date..to_date) }
end
```

and use it like

For Present - `manpower.attendance.date_between(from_date, to_date).present.count`

For Absent - `manpower.attendance.date_between(from_date, to_date).absent.count`

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Total Present</th>
      <th>Total Absent</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @manpowers.each do |manpower| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= manpower.name %></td>
        <td><%= manpower.attendance.date_between(from_date, to_date).present.count %></td>
        <td><%= manpower.attendance.date_between(from_date, to_date).absent.count %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: getting error like ```The scope body needs to be callable.```

Comment: @rock Could you please post your scope definition in the comment?

Comment: i don't know define scope but ```manpower.attendances.where(attendance_date: from_date..to_date, status: 1).count``` worked